# Why does the order of implicit parameters sometimes matter?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

Regarding following piece of code (scala `2.12.10`) my question is why order matter in that specific case for implicit arguments. I also doesn't understand why compiler tells me that there is ambiguous implicit values, i see any of hint about it.

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait Wrapper[T] {

  implicit def ct: ClassTag[T]

  // First try using scala syntaxic sugar for single type parameter type class
  def asPair1[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](implicit ev: T <:< (K, V)): Unit = Unit
  
  // Same as asPair1 with explicit implicits ClassTag, in same order than with syntaxic sugar version
  def asPair1Bis[K, V](implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ev: T <:< (K, V)): Unit = Unit

  // Workaround
  def asPair2[K, V](implicit ev: T <:< (K, V), kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V]): Unit = Unit
  
}

trait Test[K, V] {
  
  implicit def kt: ClassTag[K]
  implicit def vt: ClassTag[V]
  
  val w: Wrapper[(K, V)]
  
  w.asPair1  // Fails
/**
error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method kt in trait Test of type => reflect.this.ClassTag[K]
 and method vt in trait Test of type => reflect.this.ClassTag[V]
 match expected type reflect.this.ClassTag[K]
    w.asPair1  // Fails
      ^
error: No ClassTag available for K
    w.asPair1  // Fails
      ^
error: not enough arguments for method asPair1: (implicit   evidence$1: reflect.this.ClassTag[K], implicit   evidence$2: reflect.this.ClassTag[V], implicit  ev: $less$colon$less[scala.this.Tuple2[K,V],scala.this.Tuple2[K,V]])scala.this.Unit.
Unspecified value parameters evidence$1, evidence$2, ev.
    w.asPair1  // Fails
*/

  w.asPair1Bis // Fails
  w.asPair2  // Works


  val w2: Wrapper[(Int, Double)]
  w2.asPair1 // Fails with exact same logs than with `w`
  w2.asPair2


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, do not mix context bounds and implicits, that is considered a bad practice; see [this](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/1092342965232648192) for more context.

Second, the order matters because if the `ev` comes first then the type parameters `K` and `V` are solved by the compiler before it tries to search their **ClassTags**.
In the other case, the compiler has no info about what `K` and `V` are so it will try to just assume anything it can find, thus finding two possible *implicit* **ClassTags** *(both the one for the outer `K` and the outer `V`)* creating an ambiguity.